# Unexpected result while storing the elements in array

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have written a shell script
where I am parsing the data in **interact_info** in to space newline separated arguments and storing it in **$var.**

Now I am storing it in an array so that I can send them to expect script 
like(expected result)

```
 try.exp Directory '' 'User name' admin Password pass
```

The problem here is that I am getting only 6 arguments instead of 7

like

```
try.exp Directory 'User name' admin Password pass
```

But when I change the IFS value to '\r'
I am getting the expected result.

What is the reason for this ?

```
interact_info='[{ "Directory": "" }, { "User name": "admin" }, { "Password": "pass" }, { "SMTP Server": "10.10.10.0" } ]'

old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

var=$(echo -e "$interact_info" | python -c 'import sys, json; \
stdin = sys.stdin.read()
exit(0) if stdin == "\n" else 0 ; \
interactions = json.loads(stdin); \
my_list = sum([(key, item[key]) for item in interactions for key in item],()); \
[sys.stdout.write(command+"\n") for command in my_list]' );

echo "${var}"
arr_params=($var)
IFS=$old_IFS
echo "${arr_params[@]}"  
cli_raw_op=$(try.exp "${arr_params[@]}" 2>&1);
```

Also if IFS=$'\n'
the variable will have the value

```
+ var='Directory

User name
hcsadmin
Password
hcs@dmin
SMTP Server
10.10.10.0'
```

Since '\n' is the delimiter, arr[1] should have ""(empty string)
Why it is not so?

Comment: edit: changed the title

Comment: I suspect the problem has to do with `stdin = sys.stdin.read()` rather than bash.

Comment: You have more Python code than shell in your "shell" script. Write the entire thing in Python.

Comment: Unquoted variable references, like `arr=($var)`, are parsed in a way that almost never matches what you actually want. In this case, the problem is that it treats a run if whitespace (in this case, two newlines in a row) as a single delimiter. It'll also do unpleasant things like expanding wildcards into a list of matching filenames.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks. But why it doesn't take \r as a run?

Comment: @chepner Actually the code is showed is a part of the script module

Comment: @Prajwal With `IFS=$'\r', it shouldn't split at all. You should get a single array entry (with a bunch of embedded newlines).